# Sup of holomorphic function $f$ is $\geq 2|f'(0)|$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic and $d:=\sup_{z,w\in D} |f(z)-f(w)|$. Prove that $d\geq 2|f'(0)|$ and is equal if and only if $f(z)=a_0+a_1z$